# Express server crashing due to MongoDB connection loss

Tags: express

I am having issues with an HTTP Node.js server built with:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- MongoDB 3.0.4
- iojs v2.3.3

  - `express=4.10.*`
  - `mongodb=1.4.34`

The following middleware are being used:

```
app.use(response_time());

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(body_parser.json());

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var connection_options = {auto_reconnect: false};
    MongoClient.connect(config.server.db, connection_options,  function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            log.error(err); // Logging error.
            return next(err);
        }

        req.db = db;
        next();
    }); 
});
```

The server started running at 20:40:10 and successfully handled multiple requests.

At 02:59:02, the following error started to get logged on every request:

```
02:59:02.114Z ERROR CrowdStudy: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ncphillips/Projects/crowdstudy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:555:74)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at emit (events.js:175:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ncphillips/Projects/crowdstudy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ncphillips/Projects/crowdstudy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1237:8)
```

My initial suspicion was that I was that the connection pool was filling up because I don't have anything to handle calling `req.db.close()`. I thought that passing in the options `{auto_reconnect: false}` would fix this issue by automatically closing the connection after some time, but it seems I was wrong.

Note that restarting the server fixes the issue, so I believe the problem has to do with Node rather than Mongo.

If this has to do with the connection pool, is there some setting I can pass to fix this, or can I have an end-ware that makes sure the connection always gets closed?

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoReconnect` is an option that should be passed to the server configuration:

```
MongoClient.connect(config.server.db, {
  server : { autoReconnect : false }
}, ...);
```

The [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Server.html) contains some errors: it states that the default setting is `false` (which it isn't), and it also states that `autoReconnect` should be set in an object called `socketOptions` (which it shouldn't).

You can add various event listeners to the `db` object that gets passed back, to detect when the connection to the database got closed/reconnected/...:

```
db.on('close', function(reason) { ... });
db.on('reconnect', function(db) { ... });
```

More events [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#event:authenticated).

Comment: Awesome. Aside from adding the event listeners, do you have any ideas on how I could test to make sure that this corrects the problem?

Comment: @ncphillips stop your MongoDB server while your app is running, that's how I tested ;-)

Comment: Thanks @robertklep. It took a bit more fiddling, as I needed to change the timeoutMS. My options now look like this:

    ```var connection_options = {
            server: {
                socketOptions: {
                    connectTimeoutMS: 1000,
                    socketTimeoutMS: 1000
                },
                auto_reconnect: false
            }
        };
```
I'm also using `db.on('timeout', function () { ... }` to log the request with the status code.